# Install phonegap on android studio

Tags: android, cordova

I try to configure my phonegap project on Android Studio. I create a project then i add a android studio. I import my project into Android Studio. 
I have this error:

```
    08:18:16 Migrate Project to Gradle?
         This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
         More Information about migrating to Gradle
         Don't show this message again.
08:18:17 Update Property Files
         The structure of following Android modules was changed:
         android
         Would you like to update related project.properties files?
         Only once
         Always for these modules
         Never for these modules
08:18:40 Update Property Files
         The structure of following Android modules was changed:
         android
         Would you like to update related project.properties files?
         Only once
         Always for these modules
         Never for these modules
08:18:40 AssertionError: Don't invoke waitForSmartMode from inside read action in dumb mode
```

Cordova version 6.1.1
Android API 19
JDK 1.8
Gradle 2.2.1
What shall i do ?

Thanks

Comment: From which directory  are you trying to import your project? And what is your Gradle version?

Comment: Gradle version 2.2.1 and i import my project from c:\phonegapProject

Comment: And by importing C:\phonegapProject\android ?

Comment: C:\phonegapProject\name_of_myproject create with cordova create

Comment: Did you try to import your project by the android sub-directory ?

Comment: I import my project with Android Studio Import project(Eclipse, Gradle,..)

Comment: Yes I know that, but did your try by importing the android sub-dir instead of project directory ?

Comment: yes i try to do it but the same error